# systemjs: mapping everything else to node_modules

Tags: systemjs

I am having trouble getting systemjs to work so it resolves node modules.

I have the following in my index.html:

```
<script src="./system.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('blast/test')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

This is my configuration:

```
System.config({
    baseUrl: '/',
    packages: {
        'app': {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
        }
    },

    packageConfigPaths: ['./node_modules/*/package.json'],

    paths: {
        'blast/*': 'app/*'
    }
});
```

This works fine so far. However, I want to be able to also resolve node modules like lodash. So I set paths to this:

```
paths: {
    'blast/*': 'app/*'
    '*': './node_modules/*'
}
```

Now I can import lodash fine, but when importing `blast/test` I get the error `/app/test 404 (not found)`. It seems, the package configuration isn't used anymore, this `.js` isn't appended. Anyone got any hints how to resolve this? I am using SystemJs 0.19.25 Standard.

Thanks, Robin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using map configuration here rather for your local package -

```
System.config({
  map: {
    blast: './app'
  }
});
```

The `./` is necessary to distinguish the URL space from becoming the `node_modules/app` path (probably the reason you used paths here to begin with?)

It's also advisable to use `baseURL: 'node_modules'` instead of a wildcard paths entry (and they pretty much amount to the same thing).